# How to remove 50 Hz, 100mV noise?

Tags: ac, dc, noise, resistance, capacitance

I am getting 100 mV noise signal at 50 Hz. I do not know the origin of the noise. What should I need to do to remove it?

Comment: Can you describe the DC voltage source?  resistance, voltage ? current available? signal? sensor?  and what is it's purpose.?  Is it a high impedance sensor? These are sensitive to stray line voltage E fields. Of so say so. then we can deal with the real problem with advice.

Answer (score 1):

We need to know how you're measuring this noise? If it's on an oscilloscope you probably don't have the probe grounded properly. At 50Hz it's almost certainly mains that your probe is picking up.

Comment: Everything is grounded properly. the one of the main reason for the noise is the use of transformers in the circuit. There is no possibility to make any changes in the circuit. So I have to manage something externally to subtract this noise signal.

Comment: Obviously it will be AC going into the transformer so even if you changed the AC frequency you'd still have that frequency noise present on your circuit. DC going into your transformer will NOT work. You'd have to modify your circuit to reduce the noise unfortunately.

Comment: In order to deal with ANY noise, you must know the signal or power source or load resistance. Pls define more. Otherwise we can only guess. What is this for?

Comment: I am getting this noise between 100K resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Digitize the signal when your sensor is not connected nor active. Then subtract exactly 0.02 seconds of the "noisy" input.

I've seen over 10:1 reduction, by doing this.

We need to see a schematic of your system. Please draw that.

Comment: Can you explain it further?